# How can I install pmdarima?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.8, pyramid-arima

There is a persistent error and all requirements are already satisfied.

```
C:\Users\dobri>python -m pip install --user pmdarima
Collecting pmdarima
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1a/4f/6851c8d37551efcb8cfe12539f42f0f1b42a2d28a7275f1e1f6bdd6956a2/pmdarima-1.4.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: Cython>=0.29 in c:\users\dobri\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from pmdarima) (0.29.14)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in c:\users\dobri\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from pmdarima) (0.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16 in c:\users\dobri\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from pmdarima) (1.17.4+mkl)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.19 in c:\users\dobri\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from pmdarima) (0.25.3)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn>=0.19 in c:\users\dobri\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from pmdarima) (0.21.3)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.3 in c:\users\dobri\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from pmdarima) (1.4.0rc1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\dobri\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from pmdarima) (1.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: statsmodels>=0.10.0 in c:\users\dobri\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from pmdarima) (0.10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.6.1 in c:\users\dobri\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from pandas>=0.19->pmdarima) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in c:\users\dobri\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from pandas>=0.19->pmdarima) (2019.3)
Requirement already satisfied: patsy>=0.4.0 in c:\users\dobri\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from statsmodels>=0.10.0->pmdarima) (0.5.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: pmdarima
  Building wheel for pmdarima (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\dobri\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-2rok4_p8\\pmdarima\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\dobri\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-2rok4_p8\\pmdarima\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\dobri\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-e4h0dzsn' --python-tag cp38
       cwd: C:\Users\dobri\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2rok4_p8\pmdarima\
  Complete output (28 lines):
  Partial import of pmdarima during the build process.
  Requirements: ['Cython>=0.29\njoblib>=0.11\nnumpy>=1.16\npandas>=0.19\nscikit-learn>=0.19\nscipy>=1.3\nsix>=1.5\nstatsmodels>=0.10.0\n']
  Adding extra setuptools args
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\dobri\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2rok4_p8\pmdarima\setup.py", line 250, in <module>
      do_setup()
    File "C:\Users\dobri\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2rok4_p8\pmdarima\setup.py", line 246, in do_setup
      setup(**metadata)
    File "C:\Users\dobri\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 137, in setup
      config = configuration()
    File "C:\Users\dobri\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2rok4_p8\pmdarima\setup.py", line 164, in configuration
      config.add_subpackage(DISTNAME)
    File "C:\Users\dobri\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1033, in add_subpackage
      config_list = self.get_subpackage(subpackage_name, subpackage_path,
    File "C:\Users\dobri\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 999, in get_subpackage
      config = self._get_configuration_from_setup_py(
    File "C:\Users\dobri\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 941, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
      config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
    File "pmdarima\setup.py", line 36, in configuration
      config.add_subpackage('model_selection/tests')
    File "C:\Users\dobri\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1033, in add_subpackage
      config_list = self.get_subpackage(subpackage_name, subpackage_path,
    File "C:\Users\dobri\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 995, in get_subpackage
      config = Configuration(subpackage_name, parent_name,
    File "C:\Users\dobri\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 779, in __init__
      raise ValueError("%r is not a directory" % (package_path,))
  ValueError: 'pmdarima\\model_selection\\tests' is not a directory
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pmdarima
  Running setup.py clean for pmdarima
Failed to build pmdarima
Installing collected packages: pmdarima
    Running setup.py install for pmdarima ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\dobri\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-2rok4_p8\\pmdarima\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\dobri\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-2rok4_p8\\pmdarima\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\dobri\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ugu3cswz\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=
         cwd: C:\Users\dobri\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2rok4_p8\pmdarima\
    Complete output (28 lines):
    Partial import of pmdarima during the build process.
    Requirements: ['Cython>=0.29\njoblib>=0.11\nnumpy>=1.16\npandas>=0.19\nscikit-learn>=0.19\nscipy>=1.3\nsix>=1.5\nstatsmodels>=0.10.0\n']
    Adding extra setuptools args
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\dobri\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2rok4_p8\pmdarima\setup.py", line 250, in <module>
        do_setup()
      File "C:\Users\dobri\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2rok4_p8\pmdarima\setup.py", line 246, in do_setup
        setup(**metadata)
      File "C:\Users\dobri\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 137, in setup
        config = configuration()
      File "C:\Users\dobri\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2rok4_p8\pmdarima\setup.py", line 164, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage(DISTNAME)
      File "C:\Users\dobri\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1033, in add_subpackage
        config_list = self.get_subpackage(subpackage_name, subpackage_path,
      File "C:\Users\dobri\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 999, in get_subpackage
        config = self._get_configuration_from_setup_py(
      File "C:\Users\dobri\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 941, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "pmdarima\setup.py", line 36, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('model_selection/tests')
      File "C:\Users\dobri\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1033, in add_subpackage
        config_list = self.get_subpackage(subpackage_name, subpackage_path,
      File "C:\Users\dobri\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 995, in get_subpackage
        config = Configuration(subpackage_name, parent_name,
      File "C:\Users\dobri\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 779, in __init__
        raise ValueError("%r is not a directory" % (package_path,))
    ValueError: 'pmdarima\\model_selection\\tests' is not a directory
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\dobri\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-2rok4_p8\\pmdarima\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\dobri\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-2rok4_p8\\pmdarima\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\dobri\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ugu3cswz\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix= Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Please add some more information to help people to understand your problem, eg: Operation System version, version of what you are installing, and also a little introduction of your problem.

Comment: One year and 9 months later, pmdarima still hasn't fixed this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Updated Answer 2021

As of 2021, the original Github issue ([Python 3.8 Support](https://github.com/tgsmith61591/pmdarima/issues/199)) about supporting Python 3.8 with pmdarima has been resolved (with this PR [[MRG+2] Python 3.8 support](https://github.com/alkaline-ml/pmdarima/pull/248)) and closed. It can be installed normally now with pip 21.x and Python 3.8.x and pmdarima 1.8.x:

```
(tmp) tmp$ python3.8 -m pip -V
pip 21.2.4 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
(tmp) tmp$ python3.8 -V
Python 3.8.12
...
Collecting pmdarima
  Using cached pmdarima-1.8.4-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_15_x86_64.whl (595 kB)
...
Successfully installed pmdarima-1.8.4
```

Furthermore, it can also be installed with Python 3.9.x:

```
(tmp) tmp$ pip -V
pip 21.2.4 from /path/to/tmp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
(tmp) tmp$ python3.9 -V
Python 3.9.7
(tmp) tmp$ python3.9 -m pip install pmdarima
...
Collecting pmdarima
  Downloading pmdarima-1.8.4-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_15_x86_64.whl (603 kB)
...
Successfully installed Cython-0.29.24 joblib-1.1.0 pandas-1.3.4 patsy-0.5.2 pmdarima-1.8.4 python-dateutil-2.8.2 pytz-2021.3 scikit-learn-1.0.1 scipy-1.7.2 statsmodels-0.13.1 threadpoolctl-3.0.0 urllib3-1.26.7
```

If you are still having problems with installation, make sure to update to latest `pip` (21.x) and Python versions (3.8, 3.9), and install the latest pmdarima (1.8.x).

#### Original Answer 2019

You seem to be using Python 3.8:

> c:\users\dobri\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages

Python 3.8 was just released last Oct 2019, and it is expected (or it's not surprising) that not all third-party packages completely support it yet. In fact, there is an open issue on `pmdarima`'s Github repo for supporting Python 3.8. See https://github.com/tgsmith61591/pmdarima/issues/199:

> [Python 3.8 was released on 2019-10-14](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html). It appears to be fully
> backwards compatible, we just need to pre-build wheels for it.
> Currently, some of our dependencies do not support 3.8, so we will
> have to wait for them, but this issue is to track any conversation
> around 3.8 support

Note the part about waiting for their dependencies to support 3.8, before they can build the proper wheels. You could follow that ticket and/or post your installation issues so that they'll be informed (be sure to provide *complete* environment details!).

The best thing you could do now is **downgrade to Python 3.7** and use that to install `pmdarima`. It installs OK on Python 3.7.5.

```
$ python -V
Python 3.7.5
$ python -m pip install pmdarima
...
Successfully installed Cython-0.29.14 joblib-0.14.0 numpy-1.17.4 pandas-0.25.3 patsy-0.5.1 pmdarima-1.4.0 python-dateutil-2.8.1 pytz-2019.3 scikit-learn-0.21.3 scipy-1.3.2 statsmodels-0.10.1
```

Then just migrate your project/app/script over to Python 3.8 once `pmdarima` supports it.

Comment: I have downgraded my python from 3.8 to  3.7.5 and I still cannot install pdarima.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.7 on `conda` environnement and I getting the same error, more over the `conda` installation just hangs.